# Why doesn't my UIPasteboard code work?

Tags: ios, ipad, uipasteboard

I am having a weird issue with the UIPasteboard.

I am copying text from Safari, and then in my app looking into UIPasteboard to see if it contains any data using this code:

```
[[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard] containsPasteboardTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"public.utf8-plain-text"]]
```

It's working fine with the Simulator but not working with the iPad. Is this because of any character set issue?

Comment: I have solved this issues by using UIPasteboardTypeListString Array

    [[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard] containsPasteboardTypes:UIPasteboardTypeListString];

    UIPasteboard *pasteboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
    
    if (pasteboard.string != nil) {
        [self insertText:pasteboard.string];
    }

Comment: Please add this as an answer, and then accept your own answer for people who stumble across this in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was having this issue because of character set but i am not sure it was only with the IOS 5.0 or for all version. But i have solved my problem with a simple solution,

UIPasteboardTypeListString

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPasteboard_Class/Reference.html

```
 [[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard] containsPasteboardTypes:UIPasteboardTypeListString];
UIPasteboard *pasteboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard]; 
if (pasteboard.string != nil) { [self insertText:pasteboard.string]; }
```

I hope this answer can help anyone.

Answer (score 1):

From my own experiences it appears that in iOS 5 plain text no longer ends up on the pasteboard as `public.utf8-plain-text`, but instead as `public.text`. Using `UIPasteboardTypeListString` instead of explicitly specifying the string will also work.

So I now use the following in my code to detect plain text in the pasteboard:

```
[[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard] containsPasteboardTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"public.utf8-plain-text", @"public.text", nil]]
```

or

```
[[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard] containsPasteboardTypes:UIPasteboardTypeListString]
```

Is it the case you are testing in the simulator against iOS 4.x and your iPad has iOS 5 installed?